# Python Keras LSTM " Error when checking input"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I am trying to train a LSTM RNN. This is my first time ever attempting this and using Keras. I used a guide to come up with this code.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
    lat         long        datetime                id  trip_id    mode_cat
0   39.979973   116.305745  2011-08-27 06:13:01     20  1          1
1   39.979957   116.305688  2011-08-27 06:13:02     20  1          1
2   39.979960   116.305693  2011-08-27 06:13:03     20  1          1
3   39.979970   116.305717  2011-08-27 06:13:04     20  1          1
4   39.979985   116.305732  2011-08-27 06:13:05     20  1          1
```

Where lat, long, datetime, id, trip_id is the input and mode_cat is the output (output is binary).

Here is the part of the code where I create and train the RNN:

```
def evaluate_model(trainX, trainy, testX, testy):
    verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 15, 64
    n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[1], 1
    model = Sequential()
    print("adding LSTM")
    model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features), return_sequences=True))
    print("adding dropout")
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    print("adding dense")
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    print("adding dense")
    model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
    print("adding compile")
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    print(model.summary())
    # fit network
    model.fit(trainX, trainy, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
    # evaluate model
    _, accuracy = model.evaluate(testX, testy, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
    return accuracy

def run_experiment(repeats=10):
    # repeat experiment
    scores = list()
    for r in range(repeats):
        score = evaluate_model(train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y)
        score = score * 100.0
        print('>#%d: %.3f' % (r+1, score))
        scores.append(score)
    # summarize results
    summarize_results(scores)

run_experiment()
```

I get the following result:

```
adding LSTM
adding dropout
adding dense
adding dense
adding compile
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 455414, 1)         28        
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 455414, 1)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 455414, 100)       200       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 455414, 1)         101       
=================================================================
Total params: 329
Trainable params: 329
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-5d4acc2b23d8> in <module>()
     31     summarize_results(scores)
     32 
---> 33 run_experiment()

<ipython-input-8-5d4acc2b23d8> in run_experiment(repeats)
     24     scores = list()
     25     for r in range(repeats):
---> 26         score = evaluate_model(train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y)
     27         score = score * 100.0
     28         print('>#%d: %.3f' % (r+1, score))

<ipython-input-8-5d4acc2b23d8> in evaluate_model(trainX, trainy, testX, testy)
     15     print(model.summary())
     16     # fit network
---> 17     model.fit(trainX, trainy, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
     18     # evaluate model
     19     _, accuracy = model.evaluate(testX, testy, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1152             sample_weight=sample_weight,
   1153             class_weight=class_weight,
-> 1154             batch_size=batch_size)
   1155 
   1156         # Prepare validation data.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    577             feed_input_shapes,
    578             check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 579             exception_prefix='input')
    580 
    581         if y is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    133                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    134                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 135                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    136                 if not check_batch_axis:
    137                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (455414, 5)
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feeding a RNN is a bit different than other networks as it works with sequences.

The problem in your code is the dataset format. RNNs' input should be a 3D tensor with shape `[batch, timesteps, feature]` [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6HL5.png)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM#call_arguments_2)

As you have a time-series dataset, you should preprocess your input data with a moving window scheme

You should check [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#single_step_model) about time series forecasting, where they implement this window scheme like this:

```
def multivariate_data(dataset, target, start_index, end_index, history_size,
                      target_size, step, single_step=False):
  data = []
  labels = []

  start_index = start_index + history_size
  if end_index is None:
    end_index = len(dataset) - target_size

  for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    indices = range(i-history_size, i, step)
    data.append(dataset[indices])

    if single_step:
      labels.append(target[i+target_size])
    else:
      labels.append(target[i:i+target_size])

  return np.array(data), np.array(labels)

past_history = 720
future_target = 72
STEP = 6

x_train_single, y_train_single = multivariate_data(dataset, dataset[:, 1], 0,
                                                   TRAIN_SPLIT, past_history,
                                                   future_target, STEP,
                                                   single_step=True)
x_val_single, y_val_single = multivariate_data(dataset, dataset[:, 1],
                                               TRAIN_SPLIT, None, past_history,
                                               future_target, STEP,
                                               single_step=True)
```

Here it is an illustration of the moving window procedure (taken from this [paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/10/7/2322))

[image: Moving windows procedure]

Your problem is not exactly time series forecasting so you should adapt the code from that tutorial to your problem. 
It should  be something like this:

```
def moving_window(dataset, past_history):
    data, labels = [], []
    for i in range(past_history, len(dataset)):
        indices = range(i-past_history, i)
        data.append(dataset[['lat', 'long', 'id', 'trip_id']].values[indices])
        label.append(dataset['mode_cat'][i])
    return np.array(data), np.array(labels)

PAST_HISTORY = 60
X, y = moving_window(dataset, PAST_HISTORY)
```

PAST_HISTORY is a hyperparameter that should be tuned.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: First, thank you so much for the help!
I've spent all day going over that tutorial and reading it. The moving_window function you defined, I assume that is to replace the multivariate_data function outlined in the article? Should all things following that function in the article remain the same?

Comment: Take into account that that tutorial deals with different types of time series forecasting, the one that is more similar to yours is "Forecast a multivariate time series > single step". So if you use the moving_window function instead of the multivariate_data from the tutorial to prepare your dataset, you should be able to use the same models that the tutorial explains.

Note: Of course you should also separate the dataset into training/validation. Additionally, you should also standardize the dataset. Those steps are well explained in the tutorial.

Comment: In my case should I be setting datetime and id (user id) to indices? since for each unique combination of datetime and user id it should have it's own row of lat, long, trip_id? I ask because in the tutorial they set datetime to indices.

Comment: It is not recommended to add the DateTime as a feature. As you are feeding the model with a time series ([batch, **timesteps**, feature]), the network will extract itself the relationship over time. However, you could use DateTime to create new features to add to the training dataset. For example, you can create a feature representing if it is weekend or not, or which day of the week it is, or if it is morning, afternoon, evening, etc.